# Dedicated Initializer in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, designated-initializer

I am newbie to Objective-C. I have a 'XYZPerson' Class with attributes {firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth} and I want when I write "XYZPerson *person=[[XYZPerson alloc] init]" in main, it should call my overridden 'init' method which should in-turn call my designated initializer and initializes my object with the defined values.

My Code snippets. http://pastebin.com/FfxNDDhf

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "XYZShoutingPerson.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        XYZPerson *person=[[XYZPerson alloc] init];
        if(person) {
            [person sayHello];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Person Object is NULL");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

-(id)init
{
    self=[super init];
    return [self initWithFirstName:@"Ankit" LastName:@"Sehra" DOB:01/01/2000];
}

-(id)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)aFirstName LastName:(NSString *)aLastName DOB:(NSDate *)aDateOfBirth
{
    _firstName=aFirstName;
    _lastName=aLastName;
    _dateOfBirth=aDateOfBirth;
}

    -(void)sayHello;
{
    NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@",self.firstName,self.lastName,self.dateOfBirth);
}
```

Write now the output of the program is "Person Object is NULL", I want it to print the firstName, lastName and DOB.

Comment: Which files is that code in? What is in `XYZPerson .h / .m`?

Comment: Hi ... The declarations are in .h files and implementations are in .m files. The code I pasted is in XYZPerson.m files. I think the problem was i did not put a 'return self' in the end of my designated initializer.

Answer (score 1):

If a class has several init methods, one of them is the "designated initializer".
This is the one that calls `[super initXXX]`. In your example, `initWithFirstName:LastName:DOB:` would be the designated initializer and should look like
this:

```
-(id)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)aFirstName LastName:(NSString *)aLastName DOB:(NSString *)aDateOfBirth
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _firstName=aFirstName;
        _lastName=aLastName;
        _dateOfBirth=aDateOfBirth;
    }
    return self;
}
```

(I have changed the type of the `dateOfBirth` property and the `DOB` argument to `NSString`  and will explain that later.)

All other init methods just call the designated initializer (and not `[super initXXX]`), in your example `init`:

```
-(id)init
{
    return [self initWithFirstName:@"Ankit" LastName:@"Sehra" DOB:@"01/01/2000"];
}
```

Note that (among several other errors), "01/01/2000" is not a `NSDate`, so

```
return [self initWithFirstName:@"Ankit" LastName:@"Sehra" DOB:01/01/2000];
```

does not make any sense. Therefore, to get a first working example for you, I have
changed the argument type to `NSString`.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the explanation. I got it working now, with my default 'init' calling my designated initializer. How should I pass the NSDate value ?

Comment: @user2171983: There are many possibilities to create an NSDate value. For example, `[NSDate date]` returns the current date/time. To convert a string to NSDate, use NSDateFormatter (look up the documentation or google for NSDateFormatter, there are *lots* of Q&A about that on stackoverflow).

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet the compiler is giving you plenty of warnings on that code.  You should fix them.  If it isn't, your compiler isn't tuned correctly.

First, your designated initializer doesn't return anything.

Secondly, there is no reason to override `init` and call your designated initializer.  Simply do:

```
foo = [[Person alloc] initWithFirstName:@"bob" lastName:@"dobbs"];
```

Comment: Hi ... Yes you were right, I put a 'return self' at the end of my designated initializer and now I am able to get an initialized object in my main. However I am still not able to pass the date value.      I am passing it like this 'return [self initWithFirstName:@"Ankit" LastName:@"Sehra" DOB:01/01/1988];'

Comment: `01/01/1988` is a mathematical expression.  It is not a date as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: I thought that you should always override the superclass's designated initializer (presumably `init`) and in that call the current class's designated initializer.

Comment: @nevanking Not true;  consider `UIView`.  `initWithFrame:` is the designated initializer and it calls `[super init]`.  (It likely also overrides `init` to call `initWithFrame:` with `CGRectZero`).  There are many, many, many example of a subclass providing a more specific DI that calls a generic super's DI.